# grab headers from multiple tsv/csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of tsv files where I am looking to grab column headers for all the files.

```
with open(os.path.abspath('reference/file.tsv'), 'rU') as file:
     reader = csv.reader(file)
     row1 = next(reader)
```

Currently, this snippet only reads 1 file where I have a list of files that needs to be parsed.

```
dir_path = os.path.abspath('reference/')
files = os.listdir(dir_path)
```

The name of the files are listed in `files`. How do I loop through the list of files and grab only the column headers for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this and it works.

```
import os
import csv

dir_path = os.path.abspath('reference/')
files = os.listdir(dir_path)


for f in files:
    with open(dir_path  +'/'+f, 'rU') as file:
         reader = csv.reader(file)
         row1 = next(reader)
         print row1
```

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't account for subfolders and will try to open them as a file.

Comment: Works. Now I want to save the results with the name of the file as a key and the column headers as the values. Would it be best to create a dictionary? or a list? row1.append[f] = next(reader) as a list doesn't work...

Comment: You should have a list of dictionaries (with key and value). May be this is what you are looking for: 



listdict=[]
for f in files:
 with open(dir_path +'/'+f, 'rU') as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file)
   row1 = next(reader)
   dict = {f: row1}
   listdict.append(dict)

Answer (score 1):

The `files` variable in your code is the content of the `reference` folder, meaning all files and subfolders of the folder. They are returned in a list of strings, containing only the file or subfolder name. This means that you'll have to prefix the path yourself.

Example:

```
dir_path = os.path.abspath('reference/')
files = os.listdir(dir_path)

for file in files:
    # Skip non-files
    if not os.path.isfile(file):
        continue

    with open(os.path.join(dir_path, file), 'rU') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        row1 = next(reader)
```

An alternative using the `pathlib` module:

```
for file in Path('reference/').glob('*'):
    if not file.is_file():
        continue

    with open(str(file.resolve()), 'rU') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        row1 = next(reader)
```

Wouldn't you be better off in reading the first line of each of those files, appending them to a list and then passing them to `csvreader`?

Example:

```
lines = []

with open(str(file.resolve()), 'rU') as f:
    lines.append(f.readline())

reader = csv.reader(lines)
for row in reader:
    # whatever you want to do with the parsed lines
```